# Relative database in ASP.net / php + cshtml

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, sql-server, relational-database

I am trying to write a simple relative tables webpage in ASP.net, which should show records from first table (achieved already) and after clicking on one of them, user is to be redirected to another page, showing him content of second table related to record he chose.

I want to know these things:

- Is it possible to send information from cshtml to another cshtml without using php (highly prefered)
- Is it possible to join php and cshtml?
- If neither of those are, do you perhaps know a way to create a table in php and fill it with SQL Server's database data (similary to cshtml's "@foreach(var row in db.Query(QueryString)")?

I am grateful in advance for any response.

Comment: Why are you trying to use PHP and ASP.NET?

Comment: Because i did not know one can post data using only CSHTML. I guess i did not read my tutorial well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send data to another page via query string for this task. Your links in page 1 should be generated to include an ID form the database e.g.

```
foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT * FROM SomeTable")
{
   <a href="/Page2.cshtml?id=@row.Id">@row.Name</a><br />
}
```

The above assumes you have an identity column named ID and a column called Name which contains the text for the link.

In Page2.cshtml, you get the id from the querystring:

```
var id = Request("id");
var data = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * From SomeTable WHERE Id = @0", id);
```

More reading for you here:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/192/Transferring-Data-Between-ASP.NET-Web-Pages

and here's some info about working with data in Web Pages:

http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to send information from cshtml to another cshtml without using php

It's not only possible, it's essential.  .NET and PHP have nothing to do with each other.  They would be two separate applications.

> Is it possible to join php and cshtml?

No.  .NET and PHP have nothing to do with each other.  They would be two separate applications.

> If neither of those are, do you perhaps know a way to create a table in php and fill it with SQL Server's database data (similary to cshtml's "@foreach(var row in db.Query(QueryString)")?

What do you mean by "create a table in PHP"?  Two separate applications (one in .NET and one in PHP) can both use the same backing database.  (Provided that it's a database both of them have the functionality to communicate with, but it's a pretty safe bet any major database will fit that description.)

Your .NET application can edit/display data from the database.  Your PHP application can edit/display data from the database.  The two applications don't have any knowledge of each other, nor should they.  They can have hyperlinks to each other, and you can style the pages to appear to be the same application, but they are separate applications.